# Using polyarea to calculate the area of a subcycle

Tags: matlab, area, cyclic

I was wondering how to use `polyarea` in MATLAB at different intervals. For example, I have `disp=[1,2,3,4,5.....]` and `load = [3,4,5,6,7,8....]`. I would like to calculate `polyarea(disp,load)` at every 40 rows (or intervals). disp and load are cyclic loading and displacement data, containing 1000+ rows like this. Any help is much appreciated!

**EDIT 1:** *(based on m7913d's answer)* It seems the code is somewhat not giving the answers appropriately. Is anything wrong with the code?

```
data=xlsread('RE.xlsx');
time=data(:,1);
load=data(:,2);
disp=data(:,3);
duration = 40;
n = length(disp); % number of captured samples
nCycles = floor(n/duration); % number of completed cycles
areas = zeros(nCycles, 1); % initialise output (area of each cycle)
for i=1:nCycles % loop over the cycles
    range = (i-1)*duration + (1:duration); % calculate the indexes corresponding with the ith cycle
    areas(i) = polyarea(disp(range), load(range)); % calculate the area of the ith cycle
end
```

Comment: What did you tried so far? What is the meaning of these (sub)polygons?

Comment: i mean i know i can find the area for 'A' and 'B' data set by using polyarea, but i am not sure how to do that for intervals. In short, A and B are cyclic loading and displacement, receptively

Comment: `polyarea(A(1:40), B(1:40))` will calculate the area of the first 40 points. You can use a for loop to automatically extend it to other intervals. Note that this value may be meaningless if it does not correspond with one full cycle.

Comment: thanks. can you please help me out with that code or an example code?

Comment: What is the problem with your code? Error message? Wrong output? If so, explain (f.e. using a plot)?

Comment: if i run it as a script, it gives ans as `1`. If i type manually, then it works. maybe this is a simple matlab error which i am unaware of. sorry but thanks a lot for all the help!

Comment: Your script should not output anything, as all lines are terminated with a `;`, but you can inspect the result in your workspace editor or in the command window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming each cycle has the same known duration (`duration = 40`), you can calculate the area of each cycle as follows:

```
duration = 40;
n = length(A); % number of captured samples
nCycles = floor(n/duration); % number of completed cycles
areas = zeros(nCycles, 1); % initialise output (area of each cycle)
for i=1:nCycles % loop over the cycles
    range = (i-1)*duration + (1:duration); % calculate the indexes corresponding with the ith cycle
    areas(i) = polyarea(A(range), B(range)); % calculate the area of the ith cycle
end
```

**Further Reading**

As this seems a basic question to me, it may be useful to have a look at the [Getting Started](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/getting-started-with-matlab.html) tutorial of MATLAB.